# How to make a data quality error log useful to users

Tags: sql-server, bitmap

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  My team does data validations on external data before we move it into our data warehouse.  The data warehouse is a star schema (i.e., very large fact tables and small dimension tables).  One of the types of data validations we run is domain integrity / reference lookup against our dimension tables.  That is, we want to make sure that all values in certain columns of the external data match the values in our dimension tables.

My former approach to run this type of validation is to use the following technique:

```
INSERT INTO errors_table
SELECT
external_data_table.key AS row_key,
'not found in lookup table' AS error_message,
'column1' AS offending_column,
external_data_table.column_in_question AS offending_value
FROM external_data_table
LEFT JOIN dimension_table_1
ON
external_data_table.column_in_question = dimension_table_1.lookup_column
WHERE
dimension_table_1.lookup_column IS NULL
AND
external_data_table.LoadID = @input_value
```

I have a ton of SELECT statements like this, and I put them all in a stored procedure.  After we execute the stored proc, a typical row in errors_table looks something like:

```
key = 123
error_message = not found in lookup table
ofending_column = column1
offending_value = x
```

Since we do this on lots of columns (with different dimension tables), then we could potentially have a given key on multiple rows in errors_table (i.e., one row for each dimension table lookup failure).

Each of these SELECT statements are starting to become a performance issue for us.  This is happening because external_data_table is becoming very large, whereas each dimension_table is quite small (i.e., we are joining a very large table to a very small table many times).

So, a colleague recommended that I compress all of my queries into one query, such that I'm only scanning external_data_table once.  In other words, each key in external_data_table will only be written to errors_table once, rather than many times (at least, potentially).  But, under this new approach, I would have to concatenate my errors_message values and my offending_value values.  So, a typical row in errors_table would now look something like:

```
key = 123
error_message = not found in lookup table | not found in lookup table | ...
offending_column = column1 | column 2| ...
offending_value = x | 1 | ...
```

Under this new paradigm, the errors_table can become very difficult to use, given that all error_message and offending_value values are concatenated.  From whatever output method I choose, my team needs to be able to quickly get a count of how many rows failed per column.  For example, via a SELECT on the errors_table, they currently see an output of something like:

```
offending_column
count_of_offending_rows
total_count_of_rows_in_table
```

What is the best way to transform the errors_table under this new paradigm to meet this need?  The transformation needs to occur in SQL Server (e.g., no pivoting in Excel).  A colleague recommended to use bitmaps, but I don't know how that could help.  (I don't have a strong grasp of bitmaps.)

Answer (score 0):

Standard solution for your problem is a staging table which should store data only for single feed of target schema.

If you keep feeding your target schema by going through table with full data from external source, then your performance issue will be back very soon not matter how you rewrite those queries.